# My Laravel application does not empty the error bag

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

My Laravel application does not clear validation errors even after displaying them. When I navigate and come back to the form to create a new record, the errors are still being displayed. How can I fix this? Below is how I am showing errors.

```php
@if ($errors->has('uuids'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-warning text-white text-bold">
                @foreach ($errors->get('uuids') as $error)
                    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Laravel errors are automatically flashed to the session, as per docs.
Try flushing session data as a first step to track the error: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#deleting-data

Comment: Can you please show how are you passing this `$errors->has('uuids')` from controller ?

Comment: @andcl that jusk kills my session and logs me out.
@ViperTecPro I am not actually passing the `$errors` variable but using a custom forms validator that is returning the erros. According to Laracasts `$errors` is a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if you are using a wrongly configured cache dependency

Answer (score 0):

Here i created sample and it's working fine :-

```
Route::get('/formTest',function (){
    return view('testForm');
});

Route::post('/formSubmit',function (Request $request){
    if($request->get('uuids') === null){
        $message = [
            'required' => 'Name is required',
            'number'   => 'And It should be number'
        ];
    }else{
        dd($request->get('get'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['uuids' => $message]);    
})->name('submitForm');
```

Blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{  route('submitForm') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="uuids">
    @if($errors->has('uuids'))
        @foreach($errors->get('uuids') as $key => $value)
        <br>
        {{  $key.'----'.$value }}
        <br>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

[image]